# How to use scipy stats gamma pdf to update the posterior distribution?

Tags: bayesian, python, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

I'm trying to "get my bearings" performing bayesian analysis, specifically I'm exploring the Gamma-Poisson conjugate prior. The definition of the PDF is below

[image: Gamma PDF]

If the prior takes the form of `gamma(x,a,b)` it's my understanding that the posterior takes the form `gamma(a,x+n,b+1)` *where n is total events in 1 unit of time* or `gamma(x, a+<events>, b+<time>)` *for multiple units of time*.

The issue I'm running into is that scipy (A) defines the Gamma PDF slightly differently, omitting b and is unclear on what the optional variables do, such as `loc` and `scale` (see [gamma.pdf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html).) Consider the scipy definition of the PDF below.

[image: scipy definition of Gamma PDF]

My code isn't working the way that I believe it should.

```py
## class definition
class Gamma():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
    
    def update(self,batch):
        time = len(batch) # total units of time
        events = sum(batch) # total events across time
        self.a += events
        self.b += time

    def plot(self):
        span = np.linspace(0,10,200)
        density = gamma.pdf(x=span,a=self.a,scale=self.b)
        plt.plot(span,density)

## data generation
data = gamma.rvs(a=3,scale = 1,size = 1000) 

## experiment
## Divides data into equally sized batches and updates posterior distribution in each iteration.
g = Gamma()

def experiment_1(var,data,prop=0.2):
    size = len(data)
    window = int(size*prop)
    batches = [batch for batch in range(0,size,window)]
    for i in range(1,window):
        try:
            var.plot()
            curr = batches[i]
            prev = batches[i-1]                        
            batch = data[prev:curr]
            var.update(batch)
        except:
            pass

        
experiment_1(var=g,data=data)
```

Have a look at the plot, which shows the progress through multiple iterations/batches, updating the posterior.

[image: progressive posterior plot]

The best I can determine is that the scipy.stats.gamma.pdf function's scale parameter does not function the way that b ought to in the mathematical expression.

What should I do to alter this code such the posterior *correctly* updates in each iteration?

Edit: I posted a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476240/gamma-poisson-conjugate-prior-posterior-exploding) where I did not use scipy for the Gamma distribution, I only used it for the gamma function in the denominator. What I found was that for rates above ~5, the denominator exploded, resulting in numeric overflow and my code crashed.

For my purposes, I need to be plotting events on the scale of about 100-500 per day. I currently have no working solution. Please help me revise code to achieve this desired effect.

Comment: The documentation is clear: "Specifically, gamma.pdf(x, a, loc, scale) is identically equivalent to gamma.pdf(y, a) / scale with y = (x - loc) / scale."  That identifies $1/\beta$ as the scale parameter.

Comment: Wow, I can't explain why that didn't click earlier. I really just needed to change 1 line in the plot method: `density = gamma.pdf(x=span,a=self.a,scale=1/self.b)`. Feel free to post a solution, by rights the bounty is yours.

Comment: Here's a better idea: I'll refund the bounty in case you have a more pressing question to ask :-).

Comment: @whuber, much appreciated - cheers!